# How to override protected methods of a class of MVCResourceCommand in liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I want to override a protected method in the class `ExportArticleMVCResourceCommand` which extends the`BaseMVCResourceCommand` class.

I want to convert journal article's to pdf in liferay 7 . I have written this functionality in its own method and wish to call that method in the `doServeResource(...)` method. But as `doServeResource()` is protected, I am not able to call it on a button submit. Therefore, I want to ask how to override this `doServeResource()` method in liferay 7.

Comment: It must be protected for a reason,did you try looking for any other methods using that or any other approach to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

#### Dissecting the problem

Liferay 7 is an open source Java platform an as such the best way to troubleshoot (absent any documentation) is to first at the code.  You will notice that the`ExportArticleMVCResourceCommand` class extends `BaseMVCResourceCommand`.   In the `ExportArticleMVCResourceCommand` class you can see that the `doServeResource` method overrides it's parent's `doServeResource` method.  In `BaseMVCResourceCommand` there are several things to note.

1. It is an `abstract class`
2. There is  `protected abstract void doServeResource` method with no implementation.
3. The `serveResource` method simply calls the `doServeResource`

#### Piecing it together

So you want to override the `doServeResource` method in the `ExportArticleMVCResourceCommand`class because that method does not work when the "targeted extension" is of type PDF (purportedly).  You cannot override the `doServeResource` by extending or implementing any *MVCResourceCommand class or interface because it's either protected (and your OSGi component override is bundled separately) or in the case of `MVCResourceCommand` interface it doesn't exist.

#### Solution

Remember the `doServeResource` method is simply called by the `serveResource` method in `ExportArticleMVCResourceCommand`, and the `serveResource` method is public in both the `MVCResourceCommand` interface and `BaseMVCResourceCommand` class.  Therefore to override the doServeResource method you simply need to create your own OSGi component with that appropriate annotations, have it override the serveResource method, and do not the referened `serveResource` method at the end of your own.

```
@Component(
    property = {
        "javax.portlet.name=" + JournalPortletKeys.JOURNAL,
        "mvc.command.name=exportArticle"
    },
    service = MVCResourceCommand.class
public class CustomExportArticleMVCResourceCommand implements MVCResourceCommand {

    @Override
    public boolean serveResource
        (ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse) {

        // Call your custom method here
       // ExportArticleUtil.sendFile("pdf", resourceRequest, resourceResponse);
    }

    @Reference(target = "(component.name=com.liferay.journal.web.internal.portlet.action.ExportArticleMVCResourceCommand)")
    protected MVCResourceCommand mvcResourceCommand;

}
```